# Sorting Array of Objects with weekdays by date with javascript

Tags: javascript

can anybody help me sorting this array of objects by date.

```js
[{ date: "Dienstag, 07.07.20", time: "09:15", id: "18685672", … }
, { date: "Dienstag, 07.07.20", time: "13:10", id: "18685668", … }
, { date: "Freitag, 10.07.20", time: "12:05", id: "18685736", … }
, { date: "Montag, 06.07.20", time: "10:10", id: "18685684", … }
, { date: "Montag, 06.07.20", time: "14:05", id: "18685652", … }
, { date: "Donnerstag, 09.07.20", time: "14:10", id: "18685718", …}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array by a date property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property)

Comment: The thing is you don't have date objects, these are just strings that you would have to parse into dates.

Comment: Say the array is in `arr`.  then: `arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  aa=a.date.split(" ")[1].split(".").reverse().join(".")+a.time;
  bb=b.date.split(" ")[1].split(".").reverse().join(".")+b.time;
  return aa<bb?-1:aa==bb?0:1;
})`.  I'm assuming your date is NORMAL: dayOfMonth.Month.Year, unlike the silliness in USA where month comes BEFORE dayOfMonth, such as: "The 4th of July is celebrated on July 4th"... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string and sort by string.

```js
const getISO = o => {
    const [d, m, y] = o.date.match(/.{8}$/)[0].split('.');
    return `20${y}-${m}-${d} ${o.time}`;
};

var data = [{ date: "Dienstag, 07.07.20", time: "09:15", id: "18685672" }, { date: "Dienstag, 07.07.20", time: "13:10", id: "18685668" }, { date: "Freitag, 10.07.20", time: "12:05", id: "18685736" }, { date: "Montag, 06.07.20", time: "10:10", id: "18685684" }, { date: "Montag, 06.07.20", time: "14:05", id: "18685652" }, { date: "Donnerstag, 09.07.20", time: "14:10", id: "18685718" }];

data.sort((a, b) => getISO(a).localeCompare(getISO(b)));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Say the array is in `arr`.  then:

```js
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  aa=a.date.split(" ")[1].split(".").reverse().join(".")+a.time;
  bb=b.date.split(" ")[1].split(".").reverse().join(".")+b.time;
  return aa<bb?-1:aa==bb?0:1;
})
```

I'm assuming your date is NORMAL like anywhere in THE WORLD: dayOfMonth.Month.Year, unlike the silliness in USA where month comes BEFORE dayOfMonth, such as: "The 4th of July is celebrated on July 4th"... :)